# shell built-ins fail in exec statement

Tags: shell, exec, puppet, built-in, unless

I have the following exec statement:

```
exec { 'enable-locale':                                                  
  command  => 'sed -i "/^#en_US.*/s/^#//" /etc/locale.gen',                 
  provider => shell,  # for grep                                            
  unless   => 'locale -a | grep -i en_US.utf8',                             
  path     => '/usr/bin',                                                   
}
```

Which returns the following error:

> Error: /Stage[main]/Qdii::Base/Exec[enable-locale]: Could not evaluate: /bin/sh: 1: grep: not found

I find this curious, as the same shell command works fine:

```
$ /bin/sh -c 'locale -a | grep -i en_US.utf8'
en_US.utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

Confusingly, while `grep` is sometimes a builtin, in the case of Ubuntu it isn't.

```
/bin/sh -c 'which grep'
/bin/grep
```

The fix is to add the `/bin/` path to the `path` argument of the exec statement.

Comment: That a utility is installed in `/bin` does not convey a sense of being any more "builtin" than if it were installed in `/usr/bin`.  The most applicable meaning of that term I can think of at the moment is for utilities that are provided directly by the shell, as opposed to or in addition to as separate binaries.  The `test`, `echo`, and `kill` utilities are examples that may be either builtin or external (or both).

Comment: But yes, there is some inconsistency as to where various standard utilities are installed on different Unixen, and even on different Linuxes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I actually mistakenly assumed grep was a shell built-in, just like `if`, etc. That was my own mistake.